# In Godot, when I GetNode, do I access runtime nodes or the nodes of the current scene?

Tags: c#, godot

Today I discovered Godot actually sets up runtime nodes. You can see what I mean below:

[image: godot debug remote nodes]

When I run the game with debugging options, I can see these nodes under "Remote" tab in scene dock. So, that got me wondering... When I `GetNode`, do I actually access these runtime nodes?

To give an example, consider these three seperate scenes:

```
Foo
> foo: Node2D

Bar
> bar: Node2D

Container
> container: Node2D
>> foo: Node2D (injecting Foo)
>> bar: Node2D (injecting Bar)
```

In this case, `Container` scene is parent and importing/injecting `foo` and `bar`. So, in `Foo.cs`, can I access the injector, which is `container` node, as below:

```cs
// Foo.cs
Node2D container = (Node2D)GetNode("/root/container");
```

Or will this fail?

---

## Environment

- Godot Mono 3.2
- Mono JIT Compiler 6.4.0
- Manjaro 19.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I GetNode, do I actually access these runtime nodes?

You can use `GetNode` to access nodes created at runtime. Just make sure to do it not too early if the node is actually being added after the `_Ready` callback is called.

Many built-in Godot nodes will instance child nodes (mainly complex GUI controls such as GraphEdit.)

Comment: This seems to be true. I will play around a little more and, as soon as I'm sure this is the case, I will accept this as answer. Thank you very much.